# Calling DLLs using python's ctypes in OS X

Tags: python, macos, ctypes

I am working with an instrument that provided the shared libraries to use with C/C++. As my group is working with Python I wrote a ctypes wrapper using the provided DLLs (loading them with windll) and everything was working right because we were testing the code using Windows.

The final machine in which I will need to run the code is OS X, and I think I've hit a wall since the libraries the manufacturer provided don't include .so files, only .dll's.

Is there any way I can write a wrapper for using this instrument (and its provided DLL files) on Mac OS X without having access to the source code? Or would my best option be finish the program in Windows, create an executable and then running it with Wine?

Comment: Yes.  Then it may be limited,  you cannot nativilty use DLLs in Mac.

Comment: Even if you could get the source code there is no guarantee that the code would be portable, there is an awful lot of Microsoft specific APIs commonly used in C and C++ on Windows.

Comment: You _can_ use WineLib to access Windows DLLs on the Mac, and provide a backing environment for them, and so on… but yes, it's probably going to be a whole lot easier to just wrap a Windows Python interpreter (or pyInstaller executable or whatever) in Wine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough info to know what a good solution would be, but I can throw an idea or two out there. The device you have probably requires drivers, which are OS specific (in which case it is highly unlikely Wine solutions will work for you). If the device can be connected to a Windows box, but the user application runs on Mac OS, then there are some good possibilities.  You could create a Windows service that opens a network socket to send/receive data on which the user app running on Mac OS can access.  Or, instead of a Windows service, a simple Windows console app could open the socket.  The Windows service (or console app) would access the device connected to the Windows system via whatever API the manufacturer provides in their libraries while it takes commands from the socket connection and sends data back.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the Python module [zugbruecke](https://pypi.org/project/zugbruecke/)